# During runtime, Is there a way to check which API/controller method led to the current point of execution in a Spring Boot App?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Essentially, I'm implementing some dynamic logging in my Spring Boot App and need to log exceptions placed in the Service layer based on which API call led to an Exception being thrown during the execution of a method somewhere down in the Service Layer. I want to know if I can check within this method which API led us to the current point of execution?

I'm aware that I can use stack-trace to essentially trace back up to the specific Controller method that led to the current point of execution, however that involves some poor code where I'm actively checking if a StackTraceElement contains ".controller" as a substring. Additionally, The stacktrace could be extremely long if recursion is involved ..leading to inefficiency. Are there any alternatives? or can this approach be made more efficient/cleaner?

Controller:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/apiOne")
    public Response exchangeApi1(){
    ....
    someService.doMethod(params);
    ....
}

 @PostMapping(value = "/apiTwo")
        public Response exchangeApiTwo(){
        ....
        someService.doMethod(params);
        ....
}
```

Service Layer:

```
@Service
public class SomeService {
....
   public void doMethod(params){
      ....
      String api = getCallingAPI()//I need this method. Does such a thing exist in native Spring libraries?

      switch (api) {
      case "apiOne":
        LOG.error(Alert Level 1);
        break;
      case "apiTwo":
        LOG.error(Alert Level 3);
        break;
      throw BusinessException();
    .....
  }
 ......
}
```

I need something that would essentially work as the getCallingAPI() method in the above snippet.

EDIT: I realize I obviously can pass down the API name as a parameter but what I forgot to mention is that doMethod()/the exception thrown could be several service layers down and the API name will essentially be useless to a lot of the methods that eventually lead to the execution of doMethod/wherever the exception is thrown. I need something cleaner.

Comment: What if you parse the API name as a parameter to doMethod()?

Comment: @Asankasanjaya Sorry, I should’ve been more specific. The implementation of doMethod() could be several service layers down and as a result passing down the API name as a parameter will not be used by multiple methods leading to the eventual execution of doMethod(). Is there a cleaner way of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to use the [MDC](https://www.slf4j.org/manual.html#mdc) (Mapped Diagnostic Context) of your logging framework (e.g. slf4j/logback). MDC stores data on a per-thread basis, so for each user request that is an easy way to store context information.

At the moment your API is called you could set your required information in the context and clear it from the MDC before leaving the method.

```
import org.slf4j.MDC;

...

@PostMapping(value = "/apiOne")
public Response exchangeApi1() {
    MDC.put("api", "exchangeApi1");
    ....
    someService.doMethod(params);
    ....
    MDC.remove("api");
}
```

A better and cleaner way could be to extract this behaviour into an [aspect](https://dzone.com/articles/setting-up-mdc-context-with-aop-in-spring-boot-app) or [servlet filter](https://ivanursul.com/slf4j-mdc) to reduce boilerplate.

In your doMethod() you can access the api information with a simple:

```
MDC.get("api");
```

To include the MDC information in your logging output you can configure your appenders accordingly. An example for logback can be found in the [documentation](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html).